# What is the starting point of a geo-distributed server farm?

Tags: distributed-system, cluster, kubernetes

Scenario:

A web application that wants to implement geographically high availability (HA), has multiple web servers in different cities around the globe. Each server is connected to a database in the same city. These databases are configured in an active-active DB cluster, meaning each database will handle its own read and write requests, but in the background, they will sync their data. For simplicity let's say data is not sharded (partitioned) and all databases will store the same data.

Ideally a user should be connected to the nearest server. If a server goes down, users of that region should be connected to the next available server (again, the nearest). This means the latest data on a region that did not have the chance to be copied will be lost (but that's a DB architecture problem and let's keep it aside for now).

Now my question is what is the correct way to direct a user to the intended server?

I can think of two implementation:

1. A load balancer (proxy) will get the initial request and will redirect it to the intended server based on a policy (the most obvious one being the IP address)
   But if I'm correct then the load balancer itself is a fixed server on some part of the globe, which means some users access it faster than others (kinda defeats the purpose at least for the initial request).
2. Use different DNS records for each server. So, a DNS request of our domain on each region will be different.
   To my knowledge this depends on the DNS provider and the DNS software that is used, some may support it, some may not.

As a side question I would like to ask if using Kubernetes will facilitate such scenario?

Comment: I'm not best placed to explain, but I believe this is achieved at the networking layer via Border Gateway Protocol. essentially all your servers have the same IP address, but the routing is configured differently in each country, so that traffic goes to the nearest server. If a server goes down, the routing is changed to a working server. You are prob best asking on a networking forum

Comment: you can do a similar thing with different DNS records in each geo location, but the change is harder to achieve seamlessly, due to dns propagation delays

Comment: But how can I configure internet routers? All we have are some VMs around the globe that we can `ssh` to them. Can you provide a link to a guide or article?

Comment: unless you own multiple datacenters and register your own IP ranges you cant. Thats why you generally set these things up by purchasing a floating ip from an ISP or datacenter or hosting provider or cloud service etc

Comment: @Parsa99 this _sounds_ like you're trying to build something with "big enterprise" levels of reliability while not being prepared to pay for "big enterprise" levels of infrastructure. If that is the case, you and your stakeholders may need to reassess if this is a sensible/viable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 307 redirect vs transparent proxy

> 1. A load balancer (proxy) will get the initial request and will redirect it to the intended server

Please understand that you're describing two different things in that sentence.

As far as client is concerned, a proxy *is* the server.
It listens on ports {80, 443}, accepts GET requests, and sends back web documents.
This allows low latencies observed by clients.

In contrast, a client might send [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) a GET,
receive a 307 with Location: www-east.example.com,
and then the client begins the process again,
now that it has learned of a new webserver name.
This costs WAN round-trip times.

## bookmarks

For assets like JS or a JPEG image,
no one really cares and the URL can be as ugly as you like,
for example starting with "www-west", "www-east", or "www-eur".
But the web page URL visible at top of browser window
has a lot of branding power; its spelling matters a great deal.

It should typically start "www", without mentioning data center geography.

If you mess this up, people *will* bookmark ugly URLs,
and they *will* post links on social media to them.
This will force you to keep supporting ugly URLs,
long after you have shut down a data center in some geographic region.
Don't let ugly URL spellings leak out where users will use them.

## DNS and geography

When a browser causes a DNS lookup to happen,
the nameserver has an opportunity to tailor the A record we send back.
Amazon AWS and other firms offer this kind of "enhanced" DNS service.

Here is how one high tech company currently does it:

```
www.apple.com.                                     CNAME  www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net.                         CNAME  www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.  CNAME  e6858.dscx.akamaiedge.net.
e6858.dscx.akamaiedge.net.                         A      23.40.25.24
```

Note that they're contracting with Akamai.
They prefer to pay someone who's good at tracking changing WAN latencies,
rather than making substantial investments to develop that capability in-house.

Here is the approach taken by a different high tech company:

```
www.netflix.com.                                                           CNAME  www.dradis.netflix.com.
www.dradis.netflix.com.                                                    CNAME  www.us-west-2.internal.dradis.netflix.com.
www.us-west-2.internal.dradis.netflix.com.                                 CNAME  apiproxy-website-nlb-prod-1-bcf28d21f4bbcf2c.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
apiproxy-website-nlb-prod-1-bcf28d21f4bbcf2c.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  A      44.240.158.19
apiproxy-website-nlb-prod-1-bcf28d21f4bbcf2c.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  A      44.242.13.161
apiproxy-website-nlb-prod-1-bcf28d21f4bbcf2c.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.  A      52.38.7.83
```

We see multiple A records (three of them),
which lets clients auto-failover in this case to network 44
if some transient event impacts network 52 connectivity.
You can choose to similarly expose multiple addresses
in your A record lookup responses.

Imagine the two networks were geographically confined
to different continents, or different coasts.
Then a nameserver (perhaps run by AWS) could choose
to send just a single A record, corresponding to what it
believes is the closer datacenter.
Notice that this plays nicely with the concern voiced above,
since user will bookmark a "www" URL,
without remembering IP details.

## PoC

There's no substitute for experience.

Purchase client VMs in multiple geographic locations.
Ssh into them, and use `ping` + `curl` to probe webservers
from different locations.
Write down your numeric performance observations.

Purchase test server VMs in multiple geographic locations, plus DNS services.
Configure a "www" test page to be served by all webservers.
Use your clients to measure its performance.

Based on this, bring up production webservers.

Answer (score 2):

> To my knowledge this depends on the DNS provider and the DNS software that is used, some may support it, some may not.

Sure. So if this is an important feature for you, choose a provider / software which supports this.

Note there's nothing which stops you combining both your suggestions for double-redundancy - geo-aware DNS so the "happy path" hits a load balancer in your local geography, and that load balancer can then if necessary redirect the request to a different geography if the local application servers are having issues.

At some point you may decide this kind of undifferentiated heavy lifting is boring to write yourself, so you pay Cloudflare or any other number of CDN providers to do it for you.